# to open and read command prompt commands

Tags: c#, java

i need open and read command prompt results programatically. For example 
-open command prompt and using the command ping  
-i need to read and store the result datas 
someone help me out with sample programs

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
```

[MSDN -  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to accomplish with a batch script by redirecting the output to a file using '>'

For Example

```
ping www.google.com > foo.txt
```

Futher Reading: [Command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)